# Issue using multiple assignments in a single line in C

Tags: c

I need help with these 2 pieces of code. Both of them are identical except for one change.

I used `while (celsius <= upper)` in the first case and `while (lower <= upper)` in the second case.

Case 1 works fine but Case 2 isn't working as expected, ie: the loop never ends.

#### Case 1

```
#include <stdio.h>

//program to print celsius to fahrenheit table

int main (void)
{
    float celsius, fahr;
    int lower, upper, step;

    celsius = lower = 0;
    upper = 100;

    while (celsius <= upper)
    {
        fahr = celsius * (9.0/5.0) + 32.0;
        printf("%5.3f\t=\t%5.3f\n", celsius, fahr);
        celsius = celsius + 1;
    }
}
```

This worked fine.

#### Case 2

```
#include <stdio.h>

//program to print celsius to fahrenheit table

int main (void)
{
    float celsius, fahr;
    int lower, upper, step;

    celsius = lower = 0;
    upper = 100;

    while (lower <= upper)
    {
        fahr = celsius * (9.0/5.0) + 32.0;
        printf("%5.3f\t=\t%5.3f\n", celsius, fahr);
        celsius = celsius + 1;
    }
}
```

Didn't work.

`celsius = lower = 0;`

In the 2 cases, 'celsius' and 'lower' are both assigned the value 0, and both are also assigned to be equal to each other, so why don't the programs run the same when 'celsius' and 'lower' are interchanged?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `lower` and `upper` never change value inside the while loop, so the condition is always true, and the loop never terminates. At some point, the values for celsius or fahr probably becomes too large, causing the crash. (Or rather, I interpret "crashes the terminal" as "makes the terminal unresponsive". The program doesn't crash, but there is so much output you can't interact normally with the terminal anymore.)

Comment: both programs use incorrect calculation `(9/5)`

Comment: @M.M I corrected that mistake. It's now (9.0/5.0). Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second example, you set `lower` to 0 and never change it. Therefore, the loop that compares `lower <= upper` will run forever.

Comment: I wanted to ask another thing. In the first code (which was working), the terminal gave output values such as 1.000, 2.000, 3.000, and no values in between of 2 natural numbers such as 2.485. Basically it is giving float values but still something is wrong. What could it be?

Comment: @HarshitJindal: Use floating point arithmetic —  `celsius * (9.0/5.0) + 32.0` or similar.  (Personally, I prefer `fahrenheit = (celsius + 40.0) * (9.0/5.0) - 40.0;` because the reverse is `celsius = (fahrenheit + 40) * (5.0/9.0) - 40.0;`, but that's a whole separate discussion.)  What's crucial is that one of `9` and `5` is treated as floating point; then the rest will follow suit.